# How to change the format of a JSON data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I get a JSON data with this format:

```
{
 key1: val1,
 key2: val2,
 key3: val3,
 key4: val4,
 ..
}
```

Now I want to change it to another format in Javascript:

```
[
    {key: "key1", value: value1},
    {key: "key2", value: value2},
    {key: "key3", value: value3},
    {key: "key4", value: value4},   
    ...     
]
```

Is there some libraries that can do this? Or I have to write a function?

Please give me some tips! Thanx!

Comment: That’s a function that is written within a minute …

Comment: really? Today is the first day I use javascript. I am not quite familiar with it. I think I should get each item in the raw data, get key and value, then put them togerther

Comment: @CBroe But I don't know how to do the string operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var newObject = Object.keys(originalObject).map(function(k) { 
  return { key: k, value: originalObject[k] };
});
```

Comment: Where can i study more about this..?
Can you provide a useful link?
(I meant the map and key functions which i never knew existed)

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK: I don't have a useful link that happens to cover both those two functions, other than pointing to the JavaScript references. MDN is a good resource in general. You can find all the functions available on `Object` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). You should also check out the reference for [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), it has a lot of good stuff. Besides `map`, read up on `reduce`, `filter`, `some`,  `every`.